# Rails: Models associations and respective controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I'm currently working on an application where users can post videos.
Videos can have more than 1 actor and more than 1 category.
Actors can have more than 1 video.
Categories can have more than 1 video.

I'm not too sure how to set my associations between models.

Also, should I have a different controller for each model?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with a `Video` and `Actor`. Since we want a many to many relationship we need a join table. Lets call the join table `roles` and create a model for it.

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :actors, though: :roles
end

class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :videos, though: :roles
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :actor
  belongs_to :video
end
```

We can apply the same logic to categories:

```
class Video < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :roles
  has_many :actors, though: :roles
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, through: categorizations
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :video, through: categorizations
end

class Categorization < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Another way to do this is by using `has_and_belongs_to_many` which does not require a join model but [has many limitations](http://blog.flatironschool.com/why-you-dont-need-has-and-belongs-to-many/). Using a dedicated model for roles makes it trivial to add the name of the role for example and lets you query the table directly.

You could also use [polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) if you want categories to be able to apply to several kinds of models.

> Also, should I have a different controller for each model?

A good rule of thumb is at least one controller per [resource](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html) which your app exposes routes for. Remember the Single Responsibility Principle. Note that this does not mean that every model needs a controller or vice versa - every controller does not need a model.

Comment: How do you know he's using Rails 5 to ensure ApplicationRecord will work? Maybe I'm missing something, but it's not clarified in the original question.

Comment: I am indeed using Rails 5; I forgot to mention it.

Comment: @DarioBarrionuevo lucky guess.

Comment: fixed a minor copy paste error. `Role` should of course `belong_to :video` not `:role`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should have a different controller per model depending on what you're doing.

I would not advise using `has_and_belongs_to_many`. There are many articles stating the difficulty of debugging while using it. A simple google search should probably explain why. Instead, use join tables.

```
video.rb
has_many :actors, through: :video_actors
has_many :video_actors
has_many :categories, through: :video_categories
has_many :video_categories

video_categories.rb
belongs_to :video
belongs_to :category

video_actors.rb
belongs_to :video
belongs_to :actor

actor.rb
has_many :videos, through: :video_actors
has_many :video_actors

category.rb
has_many :videos, through: :video_categories
has_many :video_categories
```

Comment: Its a pretty decent answer. But it would be a lot more readable if you used `class Video ... end` and indented the contents rather than the file names for each.